# fn_listextendedproperty fails in single_user mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have an open single-user session on a SQL Server 2016.

All other queries work, but `fn_listextendedproperty` fails with `Database 'EIP_TIM' is already open and can only have one user at a time.`

It looks a bit like it tries to create a second connection internally.

[image]

The Activity Monitor looks like this:
[image]
(the selected connection is my current one)

Note that there have been schema-modifying statements after `alter database EIP_TIM set single_user`.

If I run just exactly the following block, then it succeeds.

```
alter database EIP_TIM set multi_user;

alter database EIP_TIM set single_user with rollback immediate;

   select count (*) from tabObject;
   SELECT * FROM ::fn_listextendedproperty(N'MS_Description' , N'SCHEMA',N'dbo', N'TABLE', N'tabAttribImage', N'COLUMN',N'AttribImageID');
```

But this is all part of a larger update script, and in that situation it fails.

**I know this question is at the moment a bit generic. I first wanted to ask if there are any known issues with `fn_listextendedproperty` in combination with single_user mode.**

If you need any other information, please let me know.

Comment: Upvoted for use of a .gif

Comment: Could you not use `sys.extended_properties` instead?

Comment: @Nic yes, an equivalent query against sys.extended_properties and sys.columns seems to work. A search for ``fn_listextendedproperty`` found 625 occurences, so if at all possible I would prefer to solve the original issue, but now I have at least a way out in the worst case. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like ``AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC ON`` was the culprit. OFF -> Works. ON again -> Fails again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the [big bold warnings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598%28v=sql.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) were not just for show - setting `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF` fixed the issue.